# How to set the Orientation of iPhone App in UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation

I am develop a IOS Application, I use the following code for lock the `orientation` of App.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

If the `orientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` When start the App. It will lock the `orientation` to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

But the `view` still show `Landscape` , when start the App in `Landscape`.

**How to set the `Orientation` of App to `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait` for App start whether the phone is `Landscape` or 'Portrait`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code for setting `Orientation` to `Portrait`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated] ;



    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    //set the orientation is Portrait when the App start.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
        objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:),    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to lock the whole app to Portrait then go to TARGETS -> General Tab -> Deployment Info[image]

This will lock the whole app to Portrait Mode

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one orientation for the entire app then go to targets, General, and deployment info. Then check portrait.